# Chaining two Asus Routers both with DHCP

Tags: networking, router, ip, openvpn

Here is my setup

[network topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P01c.jpg)

Router 1:
192.168.1.1 subnet: 255.255.255.0

Router 2:
IP leased from Router 1: 192.168.1.11. Own IP is 10.0.0.1 subnet: 255.0.0.0

Computer A: plugged into Router 1 with IP 192.168.1.189

Computer B: plugged into Router 2 with IP 10.0.0.79

I have a static route added to Router 1: 10.0.0.0, subnet 255.0.0.0 to gateway 192.168.1.11

I also put 10.0.0.79 in Router 2's DMZ

I can't ping from Computer A to Computer B, nor SMB to it.

Any ideas?

Router 2 is always configured to connect via OpenVPN as external Computer B traffic should always go through OpenVPN.

Comment: Bridge them, set the default gateways to the nics you want to use each wan connection. Don't Cascade or you will be double nated

Comment: *"Multiple WANs with two Asus Routers"* -- WAN means Wide Area Network.  Your title makes no sense.  Wrong acronym?  Did you mean WLAN?

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a route back from router 2 to router 1. The ping packets can most likely get to computer B, but computer B’s response can’t return to computer A.

Comment: How do I specify the reverse route? All traffic to parent IPs, 192.168.1.0 with mask 255.255.255.0 need to go to which gateway? How do I reference the parent gateway?

Comment: I added a static route for 192.168.1.0, 255.255.255.0 to 192.168.1.1 — still can't get through

Answer (score 0):

Turning off NAT on router 2
Turning off firewall on router 2
Removing Computer B from DMZ, I could ping Computer B from Computer A.
However, SMB doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you just not ping it or are you not connecting to it. Have you tried using \\IPADDRESS\DriveName where the ip is what you have set in the location of you SMB?

Comment: SNBprobably doesn't work because if different IPs. Try browsing using \\ip.ad.dr.ess\sharename

Comment: Tried both ... can't connect it seems. I can ping the computer, but there's quite a bit of delay and some loss ... has me wondering if a configuration is off.